# Subscriber Only Views on YouTube

Tags: youtube, subscriber, youtube-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

I've checked the traffic sources on YouTube analytics.
However, I do not see the checkbox for the subscriber only views that I've been reading about.
Is there any other way I can see the views coming from my subscribers only from YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

In the analytics user interface, there is (currently - I'm sure they change this UI) a dropdown in the top left that defaults to "subscribed & not subscribed"

Via the API, I haven't been able to find the equivalent parameters.

The insightTrafficSourceType dimension will give you a sum of people that arrived at your video through various 'subscriber' entry points, but this isn't the same as views by subscribers.